# Passing variables from a geometry shader to a fragment shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, geometry-shader

I have an GLSL geometry shader that looks like the following:

```
#version 150

uniform mat4 p;
uniform mat4 mv;
uniform mat3 nm;

layout(points) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 200) out;

out vec4 test;

void main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < gl_in.length(); i++) {
        ....        
        gl_Position = p * mv * gl_in[i].gl_Position;
        test = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        EmitVertex();       
        ....        
        EndPrimitive();
    }
}
```

However when I try to access "test" in my fragment shader my application crashes. Here is my fragment shader:

```
#version 150

out vec4 fColor;
in vec4 test;

void main(void) {
    fColor = vec4(test.x, 1.0, 0.4, 0);
}
```

Can someone help me to pass a variable from the geometry to the fragment shader? `varying` is deprecated in `#version 150`.

Comment: Are you sure it crashes because of your fragment shader?

Comment: What you're doing sounds ok. Where exactly is the crash occurring ?

Comment: Im using JOGL2, because I am writing this application in Java. If the shader looks right to you it realy helps me a lot, because then the bug might be somewhere else.
I don't even get a response from the GPU, so I think this might be a bug in the Java OpenGl bindings... I currently don't know which code part I should post, because I am not sure wether it helps or not... I will update my post if I know more.

Thx for the help.

Comment: Try commenting out `test`, and writing `fColor = vec4(1.0);`. If that works, `test` *might* be the problem, otherwise you can rule it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare test as input in your fragment shader (I wonder why the shader compiles):

```
in vec4 test;
```

Comment: Ah sorry, that was a typo, that occured while I stripped down the code for Stackoverflow :). However one upvote for you.